# keep footer visible when software keyboard open

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm working on a webpage for mobile devices. I have a footer that I'd like to be kept visible when the software keyboard opens.
When I search google on how to do this I only find people who complain about having this as an issue and trying to stop it from happening. But I am in the opposite situation. When the keyboard opens it just covers the footer. How can I make the footer stick to the top of the keyboard?
My css is as follows:

```
 #keyboard {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background: grey;
            padding-left: 0px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

and I have a meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My website does include a footer which has the same CSS properties (it also has `display:block;`). The meta tag I'm using is slightly different:

> < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">